# Folder search in combo box C# WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to search folder, those are placed in my local drive by using `ComboBox` just like Google suggestions. All goes well but by default it searches `.sys` files. I am wondering is there any extension of folder is available ? .

Or any other idea to search whole folder in combo box by using C# WPF ?

```
 public FileInfo[] MyCollection { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        try
        {                
            var di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\");
            MyCollection = di.GetFiles();
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code and we can see where we can help out.

Comment: Also there is no extension for a folder in Windows, instead the type (`file` vs `folder`) is stored by the OS.

Comment: are you using a  OnpenFileDialog ?

 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @eranotzp yes, I am using OpenFileDailog

Comment: @davidpilkington I updated my question please look it.

Comment: Are you looking for a list of files or folders?

Comment: @davidpilkington yes...

Comment: how about changing `di.GetFiles()` with `di.GetDirectories()`, i think it will return folders instead of file as you want. I havent tried that though, just googled and found [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7xk2b58%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you will need to change then

Change your collection to

```
public DirectoryInfo[] MyCollection { get; set; }
```

and then the fetch to

```
MyCollection = di.GetDirectories();
```

This will give you a list of folders (or directories) instead of the list of files.